# MySQL - Pesquisar número em uma string

Tags: mysql, sql, string

SGBD: MySQL

Tenho uma tabela com uma coluna do tipo Varchar, com os seguintes dados:

> ```
> id   Descrição
> 1    Pgto NF 66096 Lg Sistemas vcto: 01/10/2016.
> 2    Pgto NF 66096 Lg Sistemas vcto: 01/10/2016.
> 3    Pgto NF 1763 Criare Net vcto: 02/10/2016.
> 4    Pgto NF 1763 Criare Net vcto: 02/10/2016.
> 5    Pgto NF 1 Criare Net vcto: 02/10/2016.
> 6    Pgto NF 1 Criare Net vcto: 02/10/2016.
> 7    Pgto Fundo Fixo Ordem de Pagamneto 871159 Adria de Jesus vcto: 03/10/2016.
> 8    Pgto Fundo Fixo Ordem de Pagamneto 871159 Adria de Jesus vcto: 03/10/2016.
> 9    Pgto Tarifa Bancária  Ordem de  Pagamento 057-871159.
> 10   Pgto Tarifa Bancária  Ordem de  Pagamento 057-871159.
> 11   [Serviço Técnico de Terceiros em  Treinamento Tecnologia LED; Exper Soluçoes Luminotecas EIRELI; NF 166]  vcto: 17/10/2016.
> 12   [Serviço Técnico de Terceiros em  Treinamento Tecnologia LED; Exper Soluçoes Luminotecas EIRELI; NF 166]  vcto: 17/10/2016.
> 13   Pgto NF 2067 Interface Recursos Humanos LTDA vcto: 03/10/2016.
> 14   Pgto NF 2067 Interface Recursos Humanos LTDA vcto: 03/10/2016.
> 15   [Vale Transporte; Mês 10/16] Pagamento ao Estagiários Leandro, Bruno,  Kayo e Caio Fatura 1712317 vcto:03/10/09/2016.
> 16   [Vale Transporte; Mês 10/16] Pagamento ao Estagiários Leandro, Bruno,  Kayo e Caio Fatura 1712317 vcto:03/10/09/2016.
> 17   [Vale Transporte; Mês 10/16] Pagamento ao Estagiários Leandro, Bruno,  Kayo e Caio Fatura 1712317 vcto:03/10/09/2016.
> ```

Preciso efetuar uma Select que extraia somente os números de notas fiscais (NF) e ordens de serviços/pagamento. O problema é padrão inexistente de como os dados estão posicionados na string, pois nem sempre virá escrito "NF" ou "Ordem de Pagamento" para efetuar a busca. O Select deve ser de uma maneira que selecione somente os números das notas fiscais e ordens de serviço/pagamento, sem trazer outros dados tipo datas ou nomes, como mostra abaixo:

Resultado esperado:

> ```
> id   Descrição
> 1    66096
> 2    66096
> 3    1763
> 4    1763
> 5    1
> 6    1    
> 7    871159
> 8    871159
> 9    057-871159
> 10   057-871159
> 11   166
> 12   166
> 13   2067
> 14   2067
> 15   1712317
> 16   1712317
> 17   1712317
> ```

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Agradeço!

Comment: Você precisará de no minimo uma procedure para fazer isso. E olhe lá. É provável que você tenha de padronizar isso aos poucos com o replace e depois a procedure consiga extrair os dados tal como você quer.

Answer (score 2):

Tenta assim:

```
CREATE FUNCTION IsNumeric (val varchar(255)) 
RETURNS tinyint 
RETURN val REGEXP '^(-|\\+){0,1}([0-9]+\\.[0-9]*|[0-9]*\\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)$';

CREATE FUNCTION NumericOnly (val VARCHAR(255)) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
BEGIN
DECLARE idx INT DEFAULT 0;
IF ISNULL(val) THEN RETURN NULL; END IF;

IF LENGTH(val) = 0 THEN RETURN ""; END IF;

SET idx = LENGTH(val);
WHILE idx > 0 DO
IF IsNumeric(SUBSTRING(val,idx,1)) = 0 THEN
SET val = REPLACE(val,SUBSTRING(val,idx,1),"");
SET idx = LENGTH(val)+1;
END IF;
SET idx = idx - 1;
END WHILE;
RETURN val;
END;
```

Ai chama a função assim:

```
select NumericOnly('1&2') as result;
```

> Resultado: "12"

Mas vendo aqui acho que você vai ter que adaptar um pouco por causa das datas que tambem contem numeros

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21068063/mysql-query-will-remove-characters-from-a-string

Answer (score 0):

**MySQL**

```
SELECT * FROM tabela
WHERE campo REGEXP '^[0-9]+$';
```

**SQL Server:**

```
SELECT LEFT(subtexto, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', subtexto + 'texto') - 1) FROM (
SELECT subtexto = SUBSTRING(Nome_Campo, pos, LEN(Nome_campo)) FROM (
    SELECT Nome_Campo, pos = PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Nome_campo) FROM Nome_Tabela) e) texto
```

Answer (score -3):

usei REGEXP_REPLACE para substituir todos os caracteres nao numerico por ''
**MySQL**

```
select cast(REGEXP_REPLACE(nome, '[^0-9]+' , '')  AS UNSIGNED) from tabela
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).